# JDBC not seeing updated table structure

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, jdbc

I am using Coldfusion 8 which is connecting to SQL Server 2008, the problem is I have updated a table adding a new column in SSMS, but the JDBC connection is still 'seeing' the table prior to the change. How can I essentially 'refresh' the JDBC connection? Would restarting the cf server work?

Comment: How are you accessing the data?  SP, View, inline query?  Are you doing any query caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three things to look at:
1) do not use "select *" syntax - query plans get cached.
2) disable "maintain connections" in the CF admin - you'll take a slight performance hit, but it will help in development.
3) yes, restarting CF will clear it up, but it's not necessary for every db change.